# How To Pass Multiple 'Datas' To A View?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder

I know that you can pass data to a view using:

```
navigator.pushView(views.LoadoutView, list.selectedItem)
```

But what if I pass that data, and then want to pass another piece of data to the same view using a similar method?

Can I get/set a new property or can I write the current data to an xml file as soon as it is received?

Here is a little diagram I made of what I'm trying to achieve (I spent hours on it :P).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I've understood, you need to push multiple objects to a view at once, correct?

The data object can only be a single object or object reference, which means that if you want to push more than just your `list.selectedItem`, create a new Object (a generic one will do) that contains both your properties and push it, much like the following;

```
var myDataObject:Object = {firstPieceOfData:list.selectedItem, secondPieceOfData:yourSecondObjectHere};
navigator.pushView(views.LoadoutView, myDataObject);
```

Comment: Hmmm....wish you had posted that just a bit earlier. That would be a way around it, but would it let me push data from list1, then open up list2 and push different data in and use them both at the same time?
I ended up created a "Varaibles.as" class and using public static vars to store the data, instead of pushing it directly to the view.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how such an application would look like cause what you're trying to do sounds a little strange (I select some data on view 1, get pushed to view 2, somehow go to view 3 and select some other data and get pushed to view 2 again). I'm a little puzzled here. Anyway, the `navigator` has a destruction policy that keeps the views in memory so that you can indeed store the data object in a variable on view 2 and get to your other view, push view 2 again and overwrite the data object, you would then end up having both objects at the same time.

Comment: More like I start on view 1, select button to view 2, select data and go back to view 1, and repeat for view 3. Essentially pushing data twice to the same view. 
Interesting...how would I access previous data then; calling "data.property" gives me the current data loaded....what are the previous "datas" named?

Comment: Just to make this clear, where do you get to view 3? But if I'm not totally mistaken (still a little confused here), the methods from my previous comment do apply here. You can either set the `navigator`s destruction policy to disabled to have your views in cache, or if that isn't an option for you, use a variable that is accessible from your views and not getting destroyed on view switch. Easiest place for that might be the Main class. So push your data to view 2, store the data in that variable, get back and push again. The data object of view 2 will obviously be the one from pushed from

Comment: ... view 3, so if you access both the data object of view 2, plus the variable you set earlier, you end up having both data objects in view 2 on the second push.